# How to make a HTML spinner with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a spinner, however using `<input>` only.

I can only use

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" class="sel1" />
```

What can I do, using CSS, to create a simple spinner?

Comment: But why you want to do that

Comment: bcoz it's my project requirement

Comment: do you mean a textbox and when clicked on it shows a set of options .. with a sort of autofill?

Comment: Did you mean spinner ?

Comment: yes but client want to look it as dropdown

Comment: i think you want autocomplete like funcationality

Comment: no i just want look as dropdown

Comment: You need suggestion based input box?

Comment: What should be shown in the dropdown .. or can you please explain more on complete functionality? or else yo are going to get downvoted here by others

Comment: i have opened jQuery datepicker on its click event n set date in input box now i want its looks

Comment: if i use dropdown then how can open datepicker on it ?

Comment: So its a datepicker .. what more do you seek?

Comment: See if this can full fill you requirement http://codepen.io/Tombek/pen/JAvHC

Comment: i can't post images; what i exactly want bcoz of my reputation so plz try to understand what i m trying to say

Comment: Then simply use datepicker http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Q9835/1/)

You can accomplish this by using the `<datalist>` tag in HTML5.

Use `list` attribute in `input` tag whose value equals to `datalist` ID

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" class="sel1" list="productName"/>
<datalist id="productName">
    <option value="Pen">Pen</option>
    <option value="Pencil">Pencil</option>
    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
</datalist>
```

If you double click on the input text in the browser a list with the defined option will appear.

## UPDATE:

If you want a spinner as a `datepicker` just change the `type` attribute of `input` from **text** to **date** :

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Select Date" class="sel1" list="productName">
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Q9835/2/)

Comment: i want datepicker, not list

Comment: Change Just your type of input , and you will not need to datalist : See : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Q9835/2/

Comment: Please remove ur answer so that I can delete this question. Bcoz my original question was not same as this. Though I accept ur answer, this never solves my problem. Better to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

**my soluton is**

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
```